# Collecting values into variable

Tags: php, jquery

So, I have following list:

```
<li><a class="name" title="<?php echo $names;?></a></li>
```

And let say, you get the following names: `Steve, Mike, Sean, Ryan`.

Now, I have the following js:

```
var names= [];
function GET_NAMES ()
{
 //Something
}
```

So, when the `GET_NAMES()` function is loaded, I want to collect all the values in the `title` in the `list` and put in the `var names=[]`

How do I collect the values into variable?

Comment: `$('li a').each(function(){names.push($(this).text())})` try like this

Comment: `<li><a class="name" title="<?php echo $names;?>"><?php echo $names; ?></a></li>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var names=[]
$('li a').each(function() {
  names.push($(this).attr('title'))
})

console.log(names)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li>
    <a class="name" title="Steve"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="name" title="Steve1"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="name" title="Steve2"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="name" title="Steve3"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try this way

Comment: @steveKim glad it helps happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you will first need to select the `<a>` elements, and then you can get the title attributes for each.

```
$("li a").each(function(){
    names.push($(this).attr('title')); // this will get the title and push it onto the array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the jQuery `.map()` method and, you can also use a `data-` attribute to hold the `names`. However if you elect to use the `title` attribute then you would just need to replace `$(this).data('title')` with `this.title` in the code below:

```
var names = $('.name').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('title');
})
.get();
```

```js
var names = $('.name').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('title');
})
.get();

console.log( names );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a class="name" data-title="Steve">Steve</a></li>
<li><a class="name" data-title="Mike">Mike</a></li>
<li><a class="name" data-title="Sean">Sean</a></li>
<li><a class="name" data-title="Ryan">Ryan</a></li>
</ul>
```